# Adding throttling using requestAnimationFrame?

Tags: javascript, requestanimationframe

In the code below I'm successfully changing the `color` of the left and right arrows based on how far a `div` (shadeFinder) has scrolled on the x axis. I want to add throttling to this code. Can someone explain how? I have the example from w3Schools below but finding it hard to merge it into my code.

```
//change the color of mobile arrows based on where the shadefinder is on X-axis
function changeArrowColor(){
  var shadeFinder = document.querySelector('.fms-wrapper');
  let leftArrow = document.querySelector('.prev');
  let rightArrow = document.querySelector('.next');
  let last_known_scroll_position = 0;
  let ticking = false;

  function doSomething(scroll_pos) {
    scroll_pos = parseInt(scroll_pos/10);
    leftArrow.style.color = `rgb(${scroll_pos},${scroll_pos},${scroll_pos})`;
    rightArrow.style.color = `rgb(${scroll_pos},${scroll_pos},${scroll_pos})`;
  }

  shadeFinder.addEventListener('scroll', function(e) {
    last_known_scroll_position = shadeFinder.scrollLeft;         
    doSomething(last_known_scroll_position);
  });   
}
```

**Mozilla scroll event example with throttling:**

```
// Reference: http://www.html5rocks.com/en/tutorials/speed/animations/

let last_known_scroll_position = 0;
let ticking = false;

function doSomething(scroll_pos) {
  // Do something with the scroll position
}

window.addEventListener('scroll', function(e) {
  last_known_scroll_position = window.scrollY;

  if (!ticking) {
    window.requestAnimationFrame(function() {
      doSomething(last_known_scroll_position);
      ticking = false;
    });

    ticking = true;
  }
});
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The [`requestAnimationFrame` API](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/window/requestAnimationFrame) takes a callback function that returns a [timestamp](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/DOMHighResTimeStamp) (I'll use RAF as shorthand hereon). If you wanted to use JS to animate, you can use the timestamp to call `cancelAnimationFrame` later. But to use just for throttling, you don't necessarily need to store this value, for now.

Since you already have a variable called `last_known_scroll_position` scoped for used within `doSomething`, you don't have to pass the `scrollLeft` value to the RAF function, but instead pass the `doSomething` as the callback after setting the `last_known_scroll_position` to the current `scrollLeft` value at the time of the scroll event.

That callback will receive a `timestamp` parameter, but you don't need it. The callback can update the color based on a calculation from the `last_known_scroll_position`.

See the example below.

```js
function changeArrowColor(){
    var shadeFinder = document.querySelector('.fms-wrapper');
    let leftArrow = document.querySelector('.prev');
    let rightArrow = document.querySelector('.next');
    let last_known_scroll_position = 0;

    function doSomething(timestamp) {
        let scroll_pos = parseInt(last_known_scroll_position/10);
        let color = `rgb(${scroll_pos},${scroll_pos},${scroll_pos})`;
        console.clear()
        console.log({timestamp, color, last_known_scroll_position});
        leftArrow.style.color = color;
        rightArrow.style.color = color;
    }

    shadeFinder.addEventListener('scroll', function(e) {
        last_known_scroll_position = shadeFinder.scrollLeft;
        requestAnimationFrame(doSomething);
    });   
}

document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", changeArrowColor);
```

```css
body {
  padding:0;
  margin:20px 0;
}

.fms-wrapper {
  height: 80px;
  width: 100%;
  max-width: 100vw;
  overflow-y: hidden;
  overflow-x: scroll;
  position: relative;
  padding: 0 30px;
  margin: 0 5px;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  z-index:0;
  margin: 0;
}

.prev, .next {
  position: fixed;
  z-index: 5;
  width: 30px;
  height: 50px;
  font-size: 28px;
  line-height: 50px;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  cursor:pointer;
  color: black;
  background: white;
  box-shadow: 0 0 5px rgba(0,0,0,.5);
  text-align: center;
  pointer-events: auto;
}

.prev {
  left: 5px;
}

.next {
  right: 5px;
}

.fms-content {
  width: 400%;
  height: 50px;
  background: linear-gradient(90deg, #f0f0f0 0%, #f0f0f0 25%, #919191 25%, #919191 50%, #f0f0f0 50%, #f0f0f0 75%, #919191 75%, #919191 100%);
  box-sizing: border-box;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}
```

```html
<div class="fms-wrapper">
  <div class="prev" tabindex="0"><</div>
  <div class="next" tabindex="0">></div>
  <div class="fms-content"></div>
</div>
```

Comment: thanks for the in depth answer! really appreciate it. One question though, how is this being throttled? It seems it's still printing a timestamp a million times every time it is scrolled.. surely it should be printing the console log a lot less?

Comment: @alecbaldwin I added the console so you can see what is happening. But it doesn't use traditional throttling, because it is designed to sync with browser repaints. From the documentation: `This will request that your animation function be called before the browser performs the next repaint. The number of callbacks is usually 60 times per second, but will generally match the display refresh rate in most web browsers as per W3C recommendation.`

Comment: This answer is not correct, it won't throttle the calls to `doSomething()`. It will execute it as many times as you call `requestAnimationFrame()`.